# The best way to create a scrollable tab in the middle of the screen?

Tags: react-native, tabs, nested, react-navigation

[image]

The mobile app of Twitter has a scrollable tab in the middle of the screen when you are on your profile. The top half of the screen displaying your profile info etc doesn't change when you click on the scrollable tabs mid screen : "Tweets & replies", "Media" etc. I am wondering how one would create this? Having half the screen stay the same and then having tabs which change mid screen... At the moment I have react navigation tabs as my main navigation - so on one of these tabs (the profile tab) I want to create the same concept as the picture..

Comment: You can nest multiple navigators. Add a view at the bottom with a tabNavigator in it

Comment: Thanks! It works but I get the error "You should only render one navigator explicitly in your app, and other navigators should be rendered by including them in that navigator." I assume this is because I am putting the Tab Navigator in a View component? Not sure how to get around it though if I want the Profile screen to show as well..

Comment: Your error is belong to common mistakes in official document. https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/common-mistakes.html

Comment: Yes I know. So it’s not correct to add a nested navigator in a view. Do you know of another way?

Comment: @TamsynJennifer hello Tamsyn have you found any solution?

Comment: No I didn’t find a solution.

Answer (score 6):

Late answer but (for anyone else and future reference), react-navigation uses this package, react-native-tab-view: https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-tab-view

for their tabs.

You can nest this within a screen, just like you desire (the previous answer only addresses the navigator inside navigator and that isn't what you want).

Here is an example (not exactly like you want, but you get the idea that you can. so instead of a background image, swap it out and use a view or scrollview accordingly to create that layout):

https://snack.expo.io/@satya164/collapsible-header-with-tabview

cheers :)

EDIT: i just found a way with just using react-navigation after all:

https://snack.expo.io/@mattx/collapsible-header-tabs

check it out

and another library: https://github.com/benevbright/react-navigation-collapsible

Comment: Using react-native-tab-view seems like the best solution since react-navigation v3 was released. Did you find another solution? Just curious :)

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if you've figured it out yet, but you can nest the `TabNavigator` inside a `StackNavigator`. That way, you can have a scrollable Tab.

```
    class ProfileMenu extends React.Component{
    render() {
     return(
      //whatever you wanted at the top 
      )
     }
    }
    
    const TabNaviga = createMaterialTopTabNavigator({
      Tweets: {screen: TweetScreen,},
      Replies: {screen: RepliesScreen,},
    })
    
    const YNavigator = createStackNavigator ({
      Home:{screen: TabNaviga,
        navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
          header: <ProfileMenu navigation= {navigation} />,
        })
      }
    })
export default YNavigator
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this tutorial and followed it,

EDIT: it seems there's a new library out that supports it https://github.com/PedroBern/react-native-collapsible-tab-view

https://medium.com/@linjunghsuan/implementing-a-collapsible-header-with-react-native-tab-view-24f15a685e07

I also wrote a bit of an explaination if you are interested.

create a ScrollY with useRef and .current at the end

create a handleScroll function which returns an event like so -

```js
const handleScroll = Animated.event(
  [{ nativeEvent: { contentOffset: { y: scrollY } } }],
  { useNativeDriver: true }
);
```

Pass it down in props to the wanted component

```js
<TabNavigator handleScroll={handleScroll} scrollY={scrollY} />
```

And also the scrollY so you can use the value in the Child component aswell

pass it farther down the line to actual events like and call handleScroll in the Child Child component onScroll prop. like so

```js
<Animated.FlatList
  ...
  onScroll={handleScroll}
/>
```

And now you can use the ScrollY value wherever you want.

what it does is checking if the current route is the one we check, it then caluclates the offset and scrollToOffset function of flatlist using the flatlist refs we got from here

```js
return (
  <Pictures
    handleScroll={handleScroll}
    onMomentumScrollBegin={onMomentumScrollBegin}
    onScrollEndDrag={onScrollEndDrag}
    onMomentumScrollEnd={onMomentumScrollEnd}
    onGetRef={ref => {
      if (ref) {
        const found = listRefArr.current.find(e => e.key === route.key);
        if (!found) {
          listRefArr.current.push({ key: route.key, value: ref });
        }
      }
    }}
  />
);
```

the `onGetRef` is connected to the FlatList ref

```js
return (
  <AnimatedFlatList
    ref={onGetRef}
    scrollToOverflowEnabled
    onMomentumScrollBegin={onMomentumScrollBegin}
    onScrollEndDrag={onScrollEndDrag}
    onMomentumScrollEnd={onMomentumScrollEnd}
    onScroll={handleScroll}
    scrollEventThrottle={16}
    contentContainerStyle={{
      paddingTop: HeaderHeight + TabBarHeight,
      paddingHorizontal: 10,
      minHeight: windowHeight - TabBarHeight
    }}
    data={data}
    renderItem={({ item }) => {
      return <Comment data={item} />;
    }}
    keyExtractor={({ commentId }): any => {
      return commentId.toString();
    }}
  />
);
```

then we have these three functions which we send the flatlist as well

```js
const onMomentumScrollBegin = () => {
  isListGliding.current = true;
};
const onMomentumScrollEnd = () => {
  isListGliding.current = false;
  syncScrollOffset();
};
const onScrollEndDrag = () => {
  syncScrollOffset();
};
```

and last but not least we still need to animate the TabBar so when the header is 500 height his is 0 when the header is 450 in the y the tabbar should be 50, we do that by getting the scrollY in the props and use it to interpolate.

```js
const renderTabBar = (props: any) => {
  return (
    <Animated.View
      style={{
        top: 0,
        zIndex: 1,
        position: "absolute",
        transform: [{ translateY: tabViewHeight }],
        width: "100%"
      }}
    >
      <TabBar ... />
    </Animated.View>
  );
};
```

Comment: Please have a read of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) help page about how to format code properly.